# What happens when I restore from a dump Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to Mysql and  I wonder what happens when I trigger restore from a dump file:

I dumped some tables via this command:

`mysqldump -u csrhub -pMypass123 -h data4 data_1 users posts > /media/efs/riko/dump.sql`

Then by mistake i restored the dump into the same database (it was intended restore the dump into another database).

`mysq -u csrhub -pMypass123 -h data4 data_1 < /media/efs/riko/dump.sql`

Looking at the dump file:

`head -c 2000 dump.sql`

I see something like this:

`... /*!40000 ALTER TABLE`users`DISABLE KEYS */;INSERT INTO`users`VALUES (7...`

And my concern is: Will this restore result in inserting duplication of records?

Will it replace existing records or will it just insert the same records once again?

If yes, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use the `--no-create-info` option when you dump, the dump file contains `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` commands for each table that's dumped. When you restore it, this discards all the old table contents and replaces it.